# What does the Django "expected string or buffer" error indicate?

Tags: django, django-errors

I've been stuck with this error for quite a while now and I just can't figure out what it means. It occurs when I try to save an object to my mysql database. Any ideas?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: No, crystal ball not working. Post the traceback and the code that generates it.

Comment: Wish you could vote up comments.

Comment: It's a question about the meaning of the error in general. No need to be demeaning about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This probably means that Python is trying to execute code which is expecting a certain datatype (bool, string, int, etc.), but an other, incorrect, datatype is provided.

Answer (score 28):

Just ran into the same problem and resolved it. I instantiated a form like this:

```
data = {'date' : datetime.now} #this is the problem
form = MyForm(data)
```

That form was saved later on and django tried to set 'date' in the model. But datetime.now refers to a function rather than a date, obviously. What I wanted to do was **datetime.now()**

Maybe this helps anybody running into this in future.

Comment: I don't think it is, because it's overly specific. The OP's error message could occur in many different contexts.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to datetime parsing.  In my case this error came up in a queryset when I had changed a model field from DateField to DateTimeField and then forgotten to make and run migrations.

Comment: **Exactly** what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was appears when I use "time" library to convert date string to datetime object. I just use "datetime.strptime" instead of "time.strptime"and problem vanished.

Answer (score 1):

The datetime validator in django is in the file:

```
/path/to/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py
```

or in the site-packages of your current python interpreter.
Have a look there to see the regular expressions. In my case, the way to solve it was:

```
ended=datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time())
other=datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time())

# in the model:
ended = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True) # or
other = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, blank=True)
```

both working.

Answer (score 0):

'expiration' is this field

```
expiration = models.DateTimeField(default=7)
```

And code with error was this one:

```
ex = timedelta(minutes=expiration)                      
authobj, created = cls.objects.update_or_create(                         
    operator=operator,                                                   
    defaults={'transport':transport,'token':cls.generate_key(40),'expiration':ex}
)
```

And it was solved by setting it like this (instead of timedelta, a date)

```
ex = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=expiration)                      
authobj, created = cls.objects.update_or_create(                         
    operator=operator,                                                   
    defaults={'transport':transport,'token':cls.generate_key(40),'expiration':ex}
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
str(yourvar)
```

Ou can convert sting your variables.